# How can I create a sed command line from diff?

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm aware that `diff -e` can output an `ed` script. And my understanding is that `ed` and `sed` share their approach, but that `ed` is interactive, and `sed` is for streams.

What I would like to do is take the output of `diff -e` (or some other invocation of `diff`) and munge it into an invocation of `sed` such that invoking that command with the original "before" file as input produces output equivalent to the "after" file from the `diff` invocation. I would like to format the command as a collection of `-e <BLERG>` options passed to `sed` to avoid having to write the ed/sed script to another file.

I've tried a bunch of obvious mungings, but I'm not getting the desired (or even reasonable looking) output, and I think I'm missing some overarching thing. Is this possible?

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`?

Comment: I suppose no, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: But I do want to use it in a streaming context, like: `curl -s http://someurl.com | [Command I'm looking for] > outputFile` so `sed` seems like the natural choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could stick with ed: assuming you wanted to diff file1 and file2, and then apply the changes to file1 and write to a file named file1.b:

```
{ diff -e file1 file2; echo "w file1.b"; echo q; } | ed file1
```

Now, there should be no difference between file2 and file1.b:

```
$ diff file2 file1.b && echo "no diff"
no diff
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but the problem with this solution is that it presupposes the existence of file2. The situation I'm in is that file1 is always available. I make file2 by doing some hand-editing to file1, but file2 is periodically deleted out from under me, so the object is to create a command pipeline such that I can `cat file1 | [Command I'm looking for] > file2` to recreate file2 at will.

Comment: @ipmcc - you don't need file2; if you have the script use `cat script` instead of `diff...`  or embed your script in a _heredoc_ and pass it to `ed -s file1<<...` but really, your question doesn't make sense. The algorithm used by `diff -e` is really dumb. If you have to replace ten occurrences of "foo" that span over 40 lines with "bar" it will delete a block of 40 lines and append a new block of 40 lines instead of doing a simple `15,55s/foo/bar/g`. And if you tried to make it work with `sed` you'd spend more time to convert it (because `ed` operates backwards) than write your own.

Answer (score 2):

The `diff` and the subsequent application of the `diff` differences are at different times.  So assuming you have the output from your `diff`, I would use `patch`:

diff -u original.html new.html > original.patch

Then on the receiving end:

```
curl -s http://someurl.com > original.html; patch < original.patch
```

This does mean engineering your filenames to be the same though, as they are contained in the patch file.